# I moved my index.html to the root through vscode, and I think I broke the code?

Tags: javascript, css, file, github, deployment

I'm super new at coding so please bare with me:
I was finally deploying my project, but the index.html was not in the root of my repository so I moved its location on vscode after trying other methods that weren't working. Now, it is deployed but nothing aside from text is working now. How do I get it back?

[image: 1]

I tried moving it back in the folder, just to see if I could open it in a default browser and see what I had before but it's not showing anything there either.

Comment: Can you attach an image of your folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

After changing the location of your index.html you need to change the links inside it. the links of css and js. For example, if your index.html and css file was in the same directory your link is gonna be like this `./style.css`, but if you move your html file inside another directory your link should be like this `../style.css`. and the same thing for your js files and images

Answer (score 0):

If the index file was moved to the root directory, please make sure you have updated your link and script elements, pointing to the CSS stylesheet and Javascipt script respectively, with the appropriate path.